# What is a Dog-Trot in regards to humans?

Tags: running, walking, jogging

Unfortunatly, all the people I've asked nearly describe it as a 'relaxed jog,' which tells me nothing. (This may be a shock to some, but my locomotion consists of stumble and sprint, never anything else).

I'm told to compare it to a dog walking, but my mind can only think of limping. I don't know why.

So again; what is a Dog-Trot and what does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it happen!

Run a bleep/multi-stage fitness test on yourself and at some point you will stop walking really fast and break into a jog. If you slow that jog speed down a bit and push off the ground so you have both feet off the ground during your stride you will have the "dog-trot"